# NSScreen visibleFrame not subtracting menu bar area

Tags: cocoa

I am using `visibleFrame` method of `NSScreen` and it appears as if it is not subtracting the menu bar area from the visible rectangle (**Dock is positioned at the bottom of the screen**). It is evident from the output of the code below:

```
NSRect visibleFrame = [screenInfo visibleFrame];
NSLog(@"\nx=%f , y=%f\nw=%f , h=%f",visibleFrame.origin.x,visibleFrame.origin.y,visibleFrame.size.width,visibleFrame.size.height);
NSRect screenFrame1 = [screenInfo frame];
NSLog(@"\nx=%f , y=%f\nw=%f , h=%f",screenFrame1.origin.x,screenFrame1.origin.y,screenFrame1.size.width,screenFrame1.size.height);
```

and the Output is as below:
**Visible Rect**

```
x=0.000000 , y=80.000000
w=1920.000000 , h=1000.000000
```

**Screen Rect**

```
x=0.000000 , y=0.000000
w=1920.000000 , h=1080.000000
```

We can infer from above output that the height of the dock is 80 (because the "Y" coordinate of the origin of the visible rectangle is 80). So, the height of the visible rectangle is supposed to be:
 ***(height of screen - height of dock - height of menu bar)***
which comes out to be:
***1080 - 80 - height of menubar***
and this should be less than 1000 under any circumstances, but as seen in the output above it is exactly 1000. This means that the height of the menu bar has not been subtracted.
Is this a bug in `visibleFrame` or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Figured out the answer myself. I was using `[[NSScreen alloc]init];` to get the NSScreen object whereas I should have used `[NSScreen mainScreen];`